# Nasdaq and HML factor positive coefficient

Tags: correlation, factor-models, nasdaq

I am using the HML factor from Fama French’s website and have always assumed that a negative coefficient indicates that the portfolio has a tilt towards growth stocks.

When I however perform a simple linear regression on the Nasdaq and the HML factor I get a positive coefficient and a correlation of 0.13 from August this year going back 3 years.

This to me seems very low as I would imagine the Nasdaq is very heavily tilted towards growth with some enormous growth names in there (Facebook, Amazon , Google etc).

I’m trying to therefore understand this.

Comment: What frequency return data?  Any chance you made an error...lots of curious results are addressed by correcting one TS or another being shifted one period.  I'd also try something more clearly growth (eg, Russell 3 growth)  than the QQQ